# Which feature has highest value within extent

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online

I have a layer in which I need to find out the maximum value of a given field within the current map extent, and then return back the value from a different field.

*e.g. Find state with highest population within current extent, and return the state name.*

This is a hosted service on ArcGIS Online, so I thought the right way of going about this was to make use of [outStatistics](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html#outstatistics) to determine the maximum value of my field using the max property.  However, even if I specify the outFields to include the field I need to report back on, all I get back is the result of the outStatistics.

For example, see [this GET request](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/2/query?f=html&where=STATE_NAME%20IN%20%28%27Maine%27%2C%20%27New%20Hampshire%27%2C%20%27Vermont%27%2C%20%27Connecticut%27%2C%20%27Massachusetts%27%2C%20%27Rhode%20Island%27%29&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=POP2007%2CSTATE_NAME%2CNAME&outStatistics=%5B%7B%22statisticType%22%3A%22max%22%2C%22onStatisticField%22%3A%22POP2007%22%2C%22outStatisticFieldName%22%3A%22maxPop%22%7D%5D&callback=dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript2._jsonpCallback).

```
Out Fields: POP2007,STATE_NAME,NAME
Extent: <an extent object>
Output Statistics: [{"statisticType":"max","onStatisticField":"POP2007","outStatisticFieldName":"maxPop"}]

Result:  maxPop: 1483460
```

**Desired response:**

```
Result:  maxPop: 1483460, POP2007: 1483460, STATE_NAME: Middlesex
```

**What is the most efficient/elegant way of calculating the maximum value of one field within the current extent, finding that record, and returning a value from a different field?**

In the above example, we can forget about extent, I just want it to return the State Name that has the maximum population value.  Please also disregard the fact that counties are involved.

Answer (score 3):

syntax could vary from one underlying database to the next, but you need something like this:

WHERE > FIELDNAME=(SELECT MAX(FIELDNAME) FROM TABLENAME)

in essence 'return to me the feature with a value equal to the highest value for that particular field'

[http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3/query?where=POP2007%3D%28SELECT+MAX%28POP2007%29+FROM+states%29...](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3/query?where=POP2007%3D%28SELECT%20MAX%28POP2007%29%20FROM%20states%29&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=STATE_NAME&returnGeometry=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&f=html)

this can be used in conjunction with a spatial operator.

Comment: Weird that is working:  "Subqueries as a where clause ... are not supported."  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_standardized_queries/015400000641000000/

Comment: Note: Does not work once the spatial envelope is added:  http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Census/MapServer/3/query?where=POP2007%3D%28SELECT+MAX%28POP2007%29+FROM+states%29&geometry=XMin%3A+-89.2278219995856%2C+YMin%3A+37.881242000418013%2C+XMax%3A+-87.2442340001989%2C+YMax%3A+38.39048202282714&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=STATE_NAME&returnGeometry=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnDistinctValues=false&f=html

Comment: thats because California doesn't fall within the longitude values you provided :)

Comment: Ha, right - that's what I figured.  It would be great if the spatial parameter could run first, and the "potential" geometries were then queried with the MAX() function.

Comment: Wow, yea, did not realise you could do subqueries against a service.  Let me do some testing next week and report back...

Comment: This is near perfect.  However, it does not work correctly with an input extent. This is likely because it applies the where clause directly against the attributes, and the MAX value is not within the extent, so it returns no results unless at full extent (or when the max value across whole dataset is within extent).